# How to create a new column containing the result of 3 already created columns in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, calculated-columns

I'm trying to create a new column whose result is the addition of three other already created columns. I want column TotalActiveMinutes to equal the sum of columns VeryActiveMinutes, FairlyActiveMinutes, LightlyActiveMinutes, and SedentaryActiveMinutes for every single row in my table. I've already created the column but can't figure out how to input the results from my SELECT query into the TotalActiveMinutes column.

```
ALTER TABLE all_activity
ADD COLUMN TotalActiveMinutes INT;

SELECT (VeryActiveMinutes + FairlyActiveMinutes + LightlyActiveMinutes + SedentaryMinutes) AS TotalMinutes
FROM all_activity;
```

I've tried the code below, which runs without error but doesn't result in anything. For instance, after selecting * from the TotalActiveMinutes column every space is still saying "null."

```
INSERT INTO all_activity(TotalActiveMinutes)
    SELECT (VeryActiveMinutes + FairlyActiveMinutes + LightlyActiveMinutes + SedentaryMinutes)
    FROM all_activity;

SELECT TotalActiveMinutes FROM all_activity;
```

Comment: I think you need an update statement instead of insert.

Comment: Thanks so much, @ReinisVerbelis! I'm new to SQL and trying to learn. I just tried this and it worked:

UPDATE all_activity
SET TotalActiveMinutes = (VeryActiveMinutes + FairlyActiveMinutes + LightlyActiveMinutes + SedentaryMinutes);

Comment: insert adds rows; to change columns, you use update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a generated column:

```
alter table all_activity add column TotalActiveMinutes int as
     (VeryActiveMinutes + FairlyActiveMinutes + LightlyActiveMinutes + SedentaryMinutes);
```

Comment: Thank you! I used Update as another user commented, and that worked as well. I will try this the next time I come across this task so it's another tool I'll have handy!